# oracle loop over date

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

I am having difficulties setting up a loop in Oracle. I have a table where values are stored for several days. Now I want to get the average of these values for each day.
I was attempting to set up a loop like this:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  For iDay in 01.03.20, 02.03.20, 03.03.20
  LOOP
    SELECT
      avg(values)
    FROM
      table
    WHERE
      date = 'iDay'
  END LOOP;
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply get the average value using the following query:

```
SELECT DATE,
       AVG (values)
  FROM table
 WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-03-01' AND DATE '2020-03-03';
```

Or if you want to use the loop then use the query in `FOR` loop `IN` clause as follows:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  BEGIN
  3  FOR DATAS IN (
  4  SELECT DATE '2020-03-01' + LEVEL - 1 DT
  5    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY
  6  LEVEL <= DATE '2020-03-03' - DATE '2020-03-01' + 1
  7  ) LOOP
  8  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DATAS.DT);
  9  -- YOUR_CODE_HERE
 10  END LOOP;
 11  END;
 12  /
01-MAR-20
02-MAR-20
03-MAR-20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I prefer the easier solutions. However, if I implement ```SELECT DATE,
       AVG (values)
  FROM table
 WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-03';``ìt says inconsistent datatypes. expected NUMBER but got DATE

Comment: see the answer, You are missing the date keyword before the actual date string. is date column is of date datatype?

Comment: Yes it is of DataType DATE

Comment: naming the column date made some confusion...I added DATE(for Datatype) and got: literal does not match format string

Comment: Format string? Means?

Comment: Are you executing this? Copy paste from here and check: `SELECT DATE, AVG (values) FROM table WHERE <your_DATE_column_name> BETWEEN date '2020-03-01' AND date '2020-03-03';`

Comment: @WildFly - [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) have to be YYYY-MM-DD. I suspect you're attempted to use `date '01.03.20'` to match your original query - you can't, you must do `date '2020-03-01'`. (You shouldn't rely on implicit conversions anyway; and you shouldn't use two-digit years...)

Comment: @WildFly format string is something like `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'DD-MON-YYYY'` that tells the database how to interpret a string like `'01-02-03'`. For [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) it is implicitly `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. I guess the value you used didn't match that.

Comment: SELECT lastEntry, AVG (values) FROM table WHERE lastEntry BETWEEN date '2020-03-01' AND date '2020-03-03' order by lastEntry ; Did the trick. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Problem is I get the all entries from one day not an average, i.e. basically the same result as if I would have done: SELECT lastEntry, values FROM table WHERE lastEntry BETWEEN date '2020-03-01' AND date '2020-03-03';

Comment: You need to use `group by` and `trunc` as `SELECT trunc(lastEntry), avg(values) FROM table WHERE trunc(lastEntry) BETWEEN date '2020-03-01' AND date '2020-03-03' order by trunc(lastentry);`

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using Dynamic Query within PL/SQL :

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

SQL> DECLARE
  v_result NUMBER;
BEGIN
  For iDay in 0..2
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT AVG(values) FROM mytable WHERE mydate = :i_Day ' 
      INTO v_result;
      USING iDay + date'2020-03-01';          
      
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_result );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
SELECT "date", avg(values)
FROM "table"
WHERE "date" between DATE '2020-03-01' and DATE '2020-03-03'
GROUP by "date";
```

Note, `date` and `table` are reserved words, most likely the query will without quotes.

Comment: Thank you, that works almost when combined with trunk("date"), as pointed out in the comments of the previous answer.